# My website on loading sometimes shows weird symbols and characters

Tags: html, css, wordpress, encoding

When I refresh the page again after I see this weird page my website loads normally. I want to understand why this is happening and how can I fix this? Here is the screenshot because my website does load sometimes normally.

[image: Weird Symbols and Characters]

Comment: What web server and version are you using to host the website? Is it Apache?

Comment: is there a way I can find it without contacting my hosting provider?